# MeteorJS + Bower and Dictating the Loading Order

Tags: javascript, meteor, bower

How can I control the order that MeteorJS loads my bower packages? I am using the meteor-bower package, but Meteor is loading all bower packages last.

This is no good when I need to use a jQuery plugin or something from a script in the client directory.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-bower

"If you want to use a bower library at script load time (outside of a Meteor.startup block, template handler, event, etc), you have to place the bower.json file so that it loads first (see Meteor load order). Take the deepest directory you have inside [project root]/lib/, add a bower directory, and put bower.json there."

So you cannot control how Meteor loads Bower packages directly, but you can indirectly by strategically placing the bower.json file (and its associated .bowerrc file.

I got this under control by having one bower.json in proj/lib/bower/ (for project-wide Bower dependencies) and another bower.json located in proj/client/lib/bower/loadbowerfirst/ (for client-only Bower packages; and because of how Meteor prioritizes loading files). Placing an additional file outside of /lib/ then had access to the expected Bower dependency.